# Is the math library linked statically?

Tags: c, gcc, libraries, static-linking

I was under the impression that the math library is linked statically because `-l name` links to `libname.a`, however if I try to compile with the `-static` flag, suddenly GCC can't find the math functions.

Does this means that math is not necessarily linked statically? Or is something else is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it would compile statically you would write `gcc libname.a` instead of `gcc -l libname`.

And to your question, yes math library is linked dynamically.

Comment: I think `-lname` finds both static and shared libraries, and it's also possible to do shared linking with the direct filename. The only difference is the way the library file is *found*.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess you are right, but `gcc -lname` definitely shouldn't link static by default.